# Problema Trigger After Update. Error 1644

Tags: mysql

#### Las tablas serían:

```
create table dept(  
  deptno     numeric(2,0),  
  dname      varchar(14),  
  loc        varchar(13),  
  constraint pk_dept primary key (deptno)  
)



create table emp(  
  empno    numeric(4,0),  
  ename    varchar(10),  
  job      varchar(9),  
  mgr      numeric(4,0),  
  hiredate date,  
  sal      numeric(7,2),  
  comm     numeric(7,2),  
  deptno   numeric(2,0),  
  constraint pk_emp primary key (empno),  
  constraint fk_deptno foreign key (deptno) references dept (deptno)  
)
```

#### Y el trigger es:

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger plusDesplazamiento
after update on dept
for each row
begin
declare msg VARCHAR(255);
declare numero decimal(2,0);

  set msg=concat("Localidad" + new.loc);
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = msg;
  select deptno into numero
  from deptno
  where loc=new.loc;
  update emp
    set sal=sal*1.1
    where deptno=numero;
    
end $$
```

#### La comprobación:

```
delimiter ;
update dept set loc="Nueva York" where deptno=10;
```

Y me da error 1644.0 y no actualiza en la tabla *emp*.

Comment: Hola. Sugiero que [crees un fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com), con un pequeño set de datos donde podamos ver el error.

Comment: y que datos tienes las tablas añadelo por favor

Comment: Nos tienes que mostrar qué trigger tienes en `emp`, porque ese error sale de alguna rutina definida por el usuario, que parece estar evitando que hagas ese update al final.

Comment: @Alfabravo lo acabo de solucionar

Comment: Buenísimo! Estaría bueno que compartas con todos la solución, como respuesta, acá debajo en el campo Tu Respuesta. :)

Comment: lo acabo de hacer primero he puesto la respuesta y luego lo comente @Alfabravo

Comment: @JavierG.Raya editar el código posteado por el OP no es correcto, se pierde el sentido de la pregunta y la posibilidad de que su error sea por falta de elementos en el código. Evita editar de esta forma las preguntas, el código debe permanecer exactamente igual a como lo sube el OP y las mejoras al mismo deben ser visuales, pero de ninguna manera debes añadir o quitar elementos al mismo, así sean simples `;`. Saludos

Comment: vale muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

**He encontrado tu problema :**

**1.** Unos de los primeros problema que he podido detectar es que tu concat lo separa a través del símbolo `+` y es con una `,`

**2.** Tu excepción te estaba dando un error por lo que te lo he quitado.

**3.** Tu `SELECT deptno INTO numero FROM deptno WHERE loc=new.loc;` estaba mal ya que FROM tutabla y tu pones FROM tucolumna, por lo que te lo sustitui por la tabla y quedo así : `SELECT deptno INTO numero FROM dept WHERE loc=new.loc;`

**4.** Cuando creas un trigger y se va tocar mucho es bueno añadir al principio `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tuTrigger $$` es decir si existe el trigger me lo elimina, si no pues pasa a la siguiente línea y en esa línea añade la creación del trigger de esta manera podrás modificarlo cuantas veces quieras.

## Tabla y datos

```
CREATE TABLE dept(  
    deptno NUMERIC(2,0),  
    dname  VARCHAR(14),  
    loc VARCHAR(20),  
    CONSTRAINT pk_dept PRIMARY KEY(deptno)  
);

INSERT INTO dept VALUES(10,'Hola','ESPAÑA');

CREATE TABLE emp(  
    empno NUMERIC(4,0),  
    ename VARCHAR(10),  
    job VARCHAR(9),  
    mgr NUMERIC(4,0),  
    hiredate DATE,  
    sal NUMERIC(7,2),  
    comm NUMERIC(7,2),  
    deptno NUMERIC(2,0),  
    CONSTRAINT pk_emp PRIMARY KEY(empno),  
    CONSTRAINT fk_deptno FOREIGN KEY(deptno) REFERENCES dept (deptno)  
);

INSERT INTO emp VALUES(1,'Javi','job',5,'2020-01-01',5,5,10);
```

## Trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS plusDesplazamiento $$
CREATE TRIGGER plusDesplazamiento AFTER UPDATE ON dept
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE numero decimal(2,0);
    
    SELECT deptno INTO numero FROM dept WHERE loc=new.loc;
    UPDATE emp SET sal=sal*1.1 WHERE deptno=numero;
END $$  

DELIMITER ;
```

## No hace falta :

Deja que salte el error solo a veces es lo mejor y de hecho esta parte te fallaba.

```
set msg=concat("Localidad " , new.loc);
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = msg;
```

## Pruebas :

```
SELECT * FROM dept; # Tiene el valor de ESPAÑA

SELECT * FROM emp; # Fiajos en la columna sal

UPDATE dept SET loc="Nueva York" WHERE deptno=10; # Actualizamos a UPDATE

SELECT * FROM emp; # Tiene el valor de Nueva York

SELECT * FROM dept; # El valor de la columna sal se cambia sin haberlo actualizado
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/202)